# Factory Pattern - A method is assigned to the object

Tags: java, factory

Hey so I was trying to understand the Factory pattern when the following came up:

```
public abstract class SoftwareShop { 

public OfficeProgramm holeApp(String zuHolendesProg) { 
    //Delegation der Objekterstellung an Subklasse 
    OfficeProgramm programm = createOfficeProgram(zuHolendesProg); 

    //weitere verarbeitung 
    programm.einpacken(); 
    programm.etikettieren(); 

    return programm; 
} 

//Definition der Factory Method 
protected abstract OfficeProgramm createOfficeProgram(String zuHolendesProg); 

}           

class MicrosoftOfficeFactory extends SoftwareShop{ 
@Override 
protected OfficeProgramm createOfficeProgram(String zuHolendesProg) { 
    OfficeProgramm programm = null; 
    if (zuHolendesProg.equals("Textverarbeitung")) { 
        programm = new Word(); 
    } 
    else if (zuHolendesProg.equals("Präsentation")) { 
        programm = new Powerpoint(); 
    } 
    else if (zuHolendesProg.equals("Tabellenkalkulation")) { 
        programm = new Excel(); 
    } 
    else { 
        System.err.println("Ungültig!"); 
    } 
    return programm; 
} 
}
```

What i do not understand about this is this: `OfficeProgramm programm = createOfficeProgram(zuHolendesProg);`

Why can the object programm be assigned to the method creatOfficeProgram(string param)? Do I not know anything important about the protcted thing? Or is it because it is abstract in the SoftwareShop class? I simply have no clue why this works and not object.createOfficeProgramm or something else... maybe someone can help!

Comment: The program object is assigned the value returned from the createOfficeProgram function, which creates OfficeProgramm objects

Comment: To expand on what dahui said, `OfficeProgramm  programm = createOfficeProgram(prog);` is not assigning the _method_ "createOfficeProgram" to the var named programm, rather it is assigning the _result of calling_ `createOfficeProgram(prog)` which indeed returns an `OfficeProgramm` object, so assigning an OfficeProgramm to a var of type OfficeProgramm is no problem.

Comment: but if i remember right, abstract Methods cant be called. Instead the methods in the subclasses are called. What does it call here? There is no classxy.createOfficeProgram() it is just creatOffProgram()... why does it call the method in the correct class? this makes no sense to me :(

Answer (score 0):

Hallo Herr Reifenberger,

protected is not the same as private. A protected method may be accessed from classes of the package and subclasses. As in private protected methods may be accessed from inside its own class of course.

SoftwareShop is an abstract class. It just defines which methods subklasses will have to implement and does not implement functionality itself. In the example code MicrosoftOfficeFactory is the implementation of the SoftwareShop and this MicrosoftOfficeFactory has to implement the createOfficeProgram method.

You can check this by ether adding methods to the abstract class SoftwareShop or renaming createOfficeProgram in MicrosoftOfficeFactory. Your IDE should inform you about that MicrosoftOfficeFactory has to implement the createOfficeProgram of SoftwareShop (and all other methods if present).

You have to let the code live. ;)
Try out this modified version of the MicrosoftOfficeFactory (i do not have the word, etc. classes so i commented them out).

```
package factory_pattern_a_method_is_assigned_to_the_object;


class MicrosoftOfficeFactory extends SoftwareShop{ 
@Override 

protected OfficeProgramm createOfficeProgram(String zuHolendesProg) { 
OfficeProgramm programm = null; 
if (zuHolendesProg.equals("Textverarbeitung")) { 
    //programm = new Word(); 
    System.out.println("Text w00t");
} 
else if (zuHolendesProg.equals("Präsentation")) { 
    //programm = new Powerpoint(); 
} 
else if (zuHolendesProg.equals("Tabellenkalkulation")) { 
    //programm = new Excel(); 
} 
else { 
    System.err.println("Ungültig!"); 
} 
return programm; 
}

public static void main(String[] nyannyan){
SoftwareShop newShop = new MicrosoftOfficeFactory();
newShop.holeApp("Textverarbeitung");
}
}
```

this yields
Text w00t

So the MicrosoftOfficeFactory is run.

Comment: Yes i know that, thanks :) but i do not know why programm (object) = createOfficeProgram (method in the subclass) is possible

Comment: @Mreifenberger btw i think an abstract class is optional when using the factory pattern or polymorphism.

Comment: edit comment: i know that too thank you... but i juts dont get why it calls the method in the class implementing the functionality... normally it is like instancexy.creatOfficeProgram() ... but here is neither a class nor a instance it just calls the method like a delegate ... but the method is in a different class...

Comment: An instantiation would be `SoftwareShop newShop = new MicrosoftOfficeFactory()`. The way it is written in SoftwareShop is the way how an abstract class is described. Abstract classes are not instantiated themself, they are just used for description though i must admit it looks strange. ;) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

Comment: thanks Lord, i really appreciate your help :) i will try it tomorrow again, maybe i am just too tired :) if i still dont get it tomorrow i will ask my teacher on friday and post the answer here if anyone ever has the same prob :)

Comment: wait i just noticed my problem: how does this class know which class has to be called? because in the example there is only MicrosoftOfficeClass but there could be another AppleThingyClass which can create other office programs... how does it know which class, much more which of those creatOfficeProgram to call?

Comment: @Mreifenberger added an example. I guess the AppleThingy would also be a subclass of the SoftwareShop? Well thats the point of the factory pattern, the Microsoft, Apple, or whatever Shop is hidden behind the SoftwareShop class. I recommend reading this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29#Subtyping

Comment: And yes in some part of the code someone will instantiate maybe a MicrosoftOfficeFactory as a SoftwareShop (like in the example), but because it is instantiated as MicrosoftOfficeFactory the jvm knows what to do. From the outside the object will be treated as SoftwareShop. Schlafen sie erstmal gut. ;)

Comment: I got it! I forgot that this was just the functionality, not the real use of it... so i just have to instantiate as you said an eg aplleShop (which is a SoftwareShop) to creat an OfficeProgram from there... totally forgot about that.... i feel so stupid right now. Thanks Lord! :) Schlaf auch gut, wann auch immer du schlafen gehst :P